# Random graph is not r-colorable w.h.p.

Tags: probability, coloring, random-graphs

I need to prove that for fixed integer $r \geq 3$ and for any constant $c > 2r\ln{r}-\ln{r}$ random graph $G\left(n, \frac{c}{n}\right)$ is not r-colorable with high probability, i.e.
$$
P\left(\chi\left(G\left(n, \frac{c}{n}\right)\right) > r\right) \longrightarrow 1.
$$
I have tried to count the expectation of the number of $r$-colorings in order to use the first moment method. But I don`t see any ways to count the expectation except to consider all partitions of $n$ in sums $k_1 + \dots + k_r = n$ (two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition) and then the expectation would look like this
$$
\sum_{k_1 + \dots + k_r = n} (1-p)^{{k_1 \choose 2} + \dots + {k_{r-1} \choose 2} + {(n-(k_1 + \dots + k_{r-1})) \choose 2}}.
$$
This looks like the wrong approach. Could you give any ideas?

Comment: Likely not all that helpful, but you can try look at the probability that $G(n, \frac{c}{n})$ contains an $(r+1)$-clique.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez That probability is very low. With high probability, $G(n, \frac cn)$ does not even contain a $K_4$.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are trying works, but doesn't quite give the right value of $c$.

There are $r^n$ possible colorings and the probability $(1-p)^{\binom{k_1}{2} + \dots + \binom{k_r}{2}}$ is maximized when $k_1 = \dots = k_r = n/r$, when it is equal to $(1-p)^{r \binom{n/r}{2}}$. Therefore there are at most $$r^n (1-p)^{r\binom{n/r}{2}}$$ colorings in expectation. Here, we need $c > 2r \ln r$ for the expectation to go to $0$.

I was originally hoping to bound this using the independence number, which gives us a calculation of $\binom{n}{n/r} (1-p)^{\binom{n/r}{2}}$. This does even worse: we need $c > 2r \ln r + 2r$.

Comment: If $X$ equals to the number of independent $n/r$ sets, then $P(X \geq 1) \leq EX = {n \choose n/r}(1-p)^{n/r \choose 2} \leq {n \choose n/r}(1-\frac{2r\ln{r} - \ln{r}}{n})^{n/r \choose 2}$. And WolframAlpha says that it tends to infinity.

Comment: You are right; the constant $c$ is off with this method. I give a different solution, but it also doesn't quite reach $c > (2r-1) \ln r$.